# basic file handling issue in python (absolute beginner)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I made a text file by copy pasting from web, with utf-8 encoding.

Question 1

```
fhand = open('random.txt')
print(fhand)
```

gave this output
`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='random.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

Why is encoding not correct?

Question 2

```
fhand = open('random.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line, end='')
```

gave this output

random
**[ËˆrandÉ™m]** ADJECTIVE
made, done, or happening without method or conscious decision.
"apparently random violence"
synonyms:
**haphazard Â· disorganized Â· undisciplined Â· erratic Â· unmethodical Â· [more]**

The actual text file was this

random
**[ˈrandəm]**
ADJECTIVE
made, done, or happening without method or conscious decision.
"apparently random violence"
synonyms:
**haphazard · disorganized · undisciplined · erratic · unmethodical · [more]**

Why is there inconsistency?

I don't know what to google for this specific issue. Went through some "file handling" youtube videos but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I checked the original text in this tool [utf-encode-online](https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode) and it gave the output similar to the one you posted. Looks like no issues.

[Snapshot - UTF-8 encode validtion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EYLc.png)

[UTF-8 decode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4MAS.png)